# Async method signature error. Must return void, Task or Task<T>

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have an async method.

```
private static async Task InsertConnectionStatusIntoAzureDatabaseAsync(Device device)
{
   ...
}
```

I call it using

```
await InsertConnectionStatusIntoAzureDatabaseAsync(device).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Visual studio will not build saying that an `async method must return void, Task or Task<T>`

It also red squiggles the line `InsertConnectionStatusIntoAzureDatabaseAsync(device).ConfigureAwait(false);` saying :

> Task does not contain a definition for ConfigureAwait()

The usings at the top of the file are

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;
```

The .net framework it targets is 4.6.1

Comment: Do you have a conflicting class also called `Task` in your project?

Comment: Oh man! That was it. There is a class buried away in a 247,000 line file called Task! If you put this as an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: 247k lines?! I hope that's autogenerated or you really need to do some refactoring!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You almost certainly have another class in your project called `Task` which is conflicting with the .Net Framework version. You can check this by going to the definition of the `Task` type and see where it leads you. So either rename your version to something distinct (probably the best option) or use the full namespace:

```
private static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task InsertConnectionStatusIntoAzureDatabaseAsync()
{
    //snip
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can as well use namespace alias and use that in your method signatire like

```
using task = System.Threading.Tasks;

    private static async task.Task InsertConnectionStatusIntoAzureDatabaseAsync(Device device)
    {
       ...
    }
```